# FlightRadarAPI Python: Query by dates

Tags: python, api

I was looking around and couldn't find any information on how to make date based queries, something that I'm very interested on.
The use case would be

**Return all flights between date 01 and date 02 for airport X.**

The query would return something like this after being transformed into a dataframe with pandas

| Date | Time | Airline | Departure Airport |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-05-27 | 10:30am | British Airways | LHT |

I'm not looking for the number of flights,  but the flight details, such as airline, that occured between those dates.

Is this possible to do with [FlightRadarAPI](https://github.com/JeanExtreme002/FlightRadarAPI)
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spoke with the developer that says that, at the moment, the API does not return those values, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You can also get more information about a specific flight such as: aircraft images, estimated time, trail, etc.

```
details = fr_api.get_flight_details(flight.id)

flight.set_flight_details(details)

print("Flying to", flight.destination_airport_name)
```

So, in order to get the value of some **fields**, I'm using the following expression:

```
print(details['time']['real']['departure'])

print(details['time']['real']['arrival'])

print(details['time']['estimated']['departure'])

print(details['time']['estimated']['arrival'])
```

Comment: Hi @Jason-Benskin, thank you for your answer. Maybe I wasn't clear enough in my original question, but I wanted to know was if I can make a query to the API that sets a date interval, for example 2021-05-27 to 2021-06-02, for a specific airport.